# artisan or composer commands - php fatal error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I made one change in my composer.json including Facebook SDK package (http://packagist.org/packages/facebook/php-sdk).

So during the composer update I got this error

```
$ php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error: Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found in
/Users/Leandro/www/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 2644
```

After this, I can't run artisan or composer commands. Always get the same error.

I tried to remove Facebook SDK from composer json but not works.

Some help? Using --no-scripts the command works fine:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this :

```
composer dump-autload
composer update
```

i think this may or may not solve it for you ..

you may need to delete the `.json` file which can be found on `app\storage\meta`, not 100% sure but it might work ..

Comment: dump-autoload runs fine and shows "Generating autoload files", but composer update not working yet =(

Comment: have you delete the .json file from the storage directory ?

Comment: am not sure then what is the problem .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [troubleshooting checklist](https://gist.github.com/bencorlett/5572133), sounds like you need to do a php artisan dump-autoload though.

Comment: When I remove **bootstrap/compiled.php** I get Fatal Error in **bootstrap/autoload.php** line 46

Comment: Right, after removing the compiled.php file you need to regenerate it with 'php artisan dump-autoload'

Comment: Wait, so you can't perform ANY artisan or composer commands? not even 'php artisan list'?

Comment: Trying to regenerate it I get the same Fatal Error in **bootstrap/autoload.php** line 46

Comment: I would try composer install and if that doesn't work I'd create post in laravel forums http://forums.laravel.io/ sorry I couldn't be more helpful but the laravel community hasn't let me down yet.

Comment: @leabdalla did you ever solve this? Can you link to the forum post? I am having the same issue as you.

Comment: @cubsink, I don't remember exactly how I solved this, but in first months with laravel I had many problems like this and solved by re-creating all my app and migrating models/controllers/etc... One gold tip for laravel is: don't use "dev-master" in composer.json. This can make one or more packages update some thing that brokes your app entirely. So I always keep in composer.json the exactly version I'm using of the package, and check periodically if the package has updates. This way I can make backup before updating packages.

Comment: @leabdalla Okay, well I don't have an existing project with the problem. I just tried to create a new one. I tried to solve it in a bunch of different ways until I got tired and went with another language. :)